# sqlite3-dev - can conda (of Anaconda) install it instead of apt-get?

Tags: libraries, sqlite

Since I installed Anaconda, and use sqlite3 within it, I've been trying to write some C++/sqlite3 codes. However, I would like to also utilize the dev files for sqlite3 but would rather not install them via apt-get, but keep them locally inside the Anaconda tree.

Can this be done?

Linux Mint 18

Comment: You have to install it with `apt-get`.   As a general rule, you should always use `apt-get` when at all possible.

Comment: So the binary is in one place and the headers etc are in another place... That's the general rule? I'm mostly concerned with version mismatch etc, but its also annoying being in different placed...

Comment: The general rule is if you install things by any other means than `apt-get` you'll eventually get a non-functioning system.  This is particularly important for libraries used by many system applications, such as SQLite. And yes, libraries and headers don't usually live in the same place.  For C++ programs normally you shouldn't need to care about Anaconda at all, just use the system libraries and headers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I like the concept of self contained, like Anaconda, QT, etc, so maybe I'll just put them in the tree manually. After all I like to keep my library paths, etc small anyway